# Request.RedirectToRoute in Session_Start cause session to restart

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the Session_Start event, it calls an authenticate_authorize class to return an AuthResult object.

```js
public AuthResult
{
  public enumAuthResult Result {get;set;}
  public string Controller {get;set;}
  public string Action {get;set;}
}
```

If the Result is not enumAuthorized, the controller and action will be returned to the Session_Start.  Then if Request.RedirectToRoute() is used to route to the controller's action, the Session_Start will be in an infinite loop.  It seems that RedirectToRoute() always restarts the session.  Instead, if Request.Redirect() is used then proper controller's action is fired up normally.

1. What is the right way to call a controller action without using redirect in Session_Start event?
2. Should I split the authentication and authorization in Application_AuthenticateRequest and Application_AuthorizeRequest events separately?
3. If the authentication and authorization are done in separate events, how can I pass the AuthResult object to Session_Start event for it to properly redirect or route to the controller?

```js
Response.RedirectToRoute(AuthResult.Controller, AuthResult.Action);
Response.Redirect(string.Format("{0}/{1}",AuthResult.Controller, AuthResult.Action));
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the right way to call a controller action without using redirect in Session_Start event?

The right way is to use an [Authorization Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx), which runs after the action has been selected. Microsoft has included a default implementation, [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx), which serves most people's needs with users/roles, but can be inherited if you need to make a custom scheme.

AuthorizeAttribute uses the `IPrincipal` and `IUser` interfaces, which can be implemented by any custom security scheme and are implemented with ASP.NET membership and ASP.NET identity.

If you attempt to base your security on URLs, it will be nearly impossible to ensure that every route to an action will go through your security scheme. For example, by default the home page can be accessed through `/`, `/Home`, or `/Home/Index`, so if your URL based authorization only accounts for `/`, the user will be able to circumvent your security and access your home action through `/Home` or `/Home/Index`.

I would recommend against creating your own security scheme - to do so requires experience that you don't have based on your question. Instead, you should review the [MVC security overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security) to find the best option for your application and then go through a tutorial that explains how to implement it. Do note that ASP.NET identity supersedes ASP.NET membership.

Comment: Thanks.  I am trying to do authentication and authorization once at the early application pipeline such as session starts.  Using Authroization Filter would force me to decorate each controller with this attribute.   We have many applications under our IIS site.  I am even planning to write HttpModule to intercept requests on the site level before MVC handler is executed so that we can systematically enforce authentication/authorization at site level and prevent each application developer from this mundane task in their application code.

Comment: You do not need to decorate every controller action with AuthorizeAttribute. You can register it as a global filter only once in your FilterConfig file. In fact, that is the recommended way to do it - and then use AllowAnonymous atttribute to selectively allow portions of your site that don't need security.